# Recover data from corrupted sd card

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card, dd, ddrescue

My cell phone and computer can't access my SD card anymore which is maybe because of a corrupted block/sector. I tried everything as it contained some useful data i desperately need. It is still listed in *$ lsblk* but dd fails. I even tried ddrescue. It would really be great if some one could help. Following are some of the outputs:

```
$ dmesg
 mmcblk0: timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x900
 [  369.099492] mmc0: tried to reset card
 [  379.098130] mmcblk0: timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x900
 [  399.097725] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0
 [  409.097205] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
 [ 1338.184806] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x0
 [ 1338.184811] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: unable to read squashfs_super_block
 [ 1416.122514] mmc0: card 1234 removed
 [ 1432.666914] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 1234
 [ 1432.668118] mmcblk0: mmc0:1234 SA08G 7.29 GiB

$ sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/home/Documents/sd.img
dd: error reading '/dev/mmcblk0': Input/output error
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 19.9988 s, 0.0 kB/s

$ sudo ddrescue /dev/mmcblk0 /home/Documents/sd.img
ddrescue: Can't open output file: Not a directory

$ sudo ddrescue /dev/mmcblk0 /home/Documents/
ddrescue: Can't open output file: Is a directory
```

Comment: The I/O error of `dd` and how `lsblk` and what I presume is `dmesg` complain about the card suggest to me a hardware failure of the controller. I don't think you will be able to read anything from it with regular software methods, as `dd` is already really low-level. Maybe a specialized data rescue company might be able to take it apart and directly read from its storage chips, but that will surely cost a fortune.